# windowbuilder removeAllItems() is not working properly for combobox

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I have a simple hospital appointment code for my comboboxes but "removeAllItems()" seems not working and instead it's increasing the number of elements inside the Hospital combobox. Here's my code and screenshots. What i want is when i click County combobox, remove all elements in Hospital combobox. But it's not working. Sorry if this pretty noobie. [first clicking County comboxbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ME6n9.png) - [second clicking and so on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ktkgq.png)

```
countyBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { // my actionlistener for clicking County
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
        hospitalBox.removeAllItems(); // i want it to remove all items inside of Hospital combobox when i click County combobox
        
        if (countyBox.getSelectedItem() != null && !countyBox.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("")) {
            
            if (cityBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Istanbul")) {
                //my iterator for adding elements into my combobox.
                Iterator<String> traverse = hospitals.getIst(countyBox.getSelectedItem().toString()).iterator();
                
                while (traverse.hasNext()) {
                    hospitalBox.addItem(traverse.next());
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't remove all the items. Did you display the item count after the method is invoked? How do you know the problem isn't your Iterator. Did you display all the values as you add them to the combo box to actually verify the data in your "hospitals" variable?

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @camickr you are very right. let me check them...

Comment: @camickr yes, the problem was my iterator. i'm very ashamed. i solved it thank you for helping.